# Why is code being executed before forEach loop finishes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In the code below, I'm expecting the `forEach` loop to execute, then initialize the `selectedGroup` state with data created from the loop.

Upon render of the component, the loop works just fine, but the `selectedGroup` state doesn't get initialized. It seems that `selectedGroup` is trying to be initialized before the loop finishes. Any ideas?

**Code in Question:**

```
const MenuContent = ({ items, modifiers }) => {
  let groups = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    !groups.includes(item.group) && groups.push(item.group);
  });

  const [selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup] = useState(groups[0]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{selectedGroup}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Items Array Used in Code:**

```
Array [
   Object {
       "86": false,
       "description ": null,
       "group": "Liquors",
       "ingredients ": null,
       "modifiers": Array [
      "gh5OdUAQC0bCr9O0HrF8",
       ],
       "name": "Smirnoff",
       "price": 350,
   },
   Object {
       "86": false,
       "description": "Vodka, Passionfruit, Ginger, Lemon",
       "group": "Cocktails",
       "ingredients ": null,
       "modifiers": Array [
         "hzxrMy17xrikXA0yumYB",
         "sLrkn3QXOgOzbHobdIRG",
       ],
       "name": "Passionfruit Mule",
       "price": 1400,
   },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with [**useEffect**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook

```
const MenuContent = ({ items, modifiers }) => {

  const [selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
         let groups = [];
         items.forEach((item) => {
           !groups.includes(item.group) && groups.push(item.group);
         });
         setSelectedGroup(groups[0])
   },[items])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{selectedGroup}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

if you need to prevent the render until value get assigned. use with `&&` conditional operator on render

```
 return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {selectedGroup && <Text>{selectedGroup}</Text>}
        </View>
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried your solution and I'm getting an error "Can't find variable groups" - I think it's still trying to set `selectedGroups` state before `forEach` loop is finishing

Comment: no its working good please check the fork https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-davinci-wm59u

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Both solutions work, I wasn't passing items prop in properly. Thanks for the help.